Alternative to The constructor Road is deprecated
We have a simulation with the traffic library, and recently while reviewing the Java code, I found the following message: "The constructor Road(Agent, ShapeDrawMode, boolean, int, int, double, Paint, MarkupSegment...) is deprecated" in all the lines related to my 2D map modeling. I’m not sure if there is an alternative to this or if I made a mistake, because this is connected to some problems I was having with, for some reason, more cars passing through the map than through the logical model. In any case, I’m leaving one of the lines of code that show this message; perhaps the error can be seen there.
Casas1 = new Road( this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 1, 0, 0.0, green,
convertMarkupSegmentDescriptors_xjal(this.<MarkupSegmentDescriptor[]>getElementProperty("Casas1", IElementDescriptor.MARKUP_SEGMENTS)) );

We haven’t tried anything yet; this is the first time I’ve seen this part, and I don’t quite understand the official AnyLogic page.

I'd hazard a guess from https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/markup/Road.html that you just use Casas1 = new Road() and then use the methods  to construct the new road. though my knowledge in this code is limited.

Sure, but in AnyLogic you can't edit the code directly, so you would be using the 'draw' option to create the roads. Thanks

So did you draw the roads in the old model or create them programmatically?

We draw the map from the AnyLogic palette since we can't edit the internal code. That's why I had the doubt. I think it's the only way to create a map that shows the agents using the traffic library.

I just created a new model to see if it was a problem with my file, but the same message keeps appearing, and the code still has the 'new Road'. calle2 = new Road( this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 1, 1, 0.0, green, convertMarkupSegmentDescriptors_xjal(this.<MarkupSegmentDescriptor[]>getElementProperty("calle2", IElementDescriptor.MARKUP_SEGMENTS)) );
